# RecyclerView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, uiscrollview, material-design, android-recyclerview

I am creating a Navigation Drawer following Google Material Design guidelines.

Like Gmail or Inbox, all drawer should be scrollable (not just the recyclerView like in Youtube app), I got this with the recyclerView. The problem is that I need that recyclerview parent view is wrap_content, but if I do this, the height of this view is equal to zero.

How can I notify to this view that this height is wrong, and it should be resize to get the correct height?.

I think that this is the problem, the view load with height = 0, and later the recyclerview is loaded, but this view doesn't know this last change.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Never use a Recyclerview (or a scrollable view) inside a ScrollView

Comment: Then how can I get the nav drawer of that apps

Comment: Use a LInearLayout instead of a RecyclerView in your navDrawer, for example

Comment: You want to say that I create a lot ot different items individually?

Comment: Is it possible to get the height of the items?

Comment: I think it will be better if you posted your navigation drawer code and  layout